# How to get clockwise angle between 2 angle on unit circle

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I think it's an easy trigonometric problem I have.
According the following figures **A** and **B**:

### [Figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCfw.png)

**What is the formula to get the clockwise angle between the two angle in the two situations?**

Figure A: Point A (15°) Point B (45°) Angle: 330°
Figure B: Point A (45°) Point B (135°) Angle: 90°

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reasons this has a Javascript tag?

Comment: @Keith : I'm actually using Javascript at the moment to calculate this angle.
The problem is that angle is the smallest possible between the two it's not clockwise.

`function diff(angle1, angle2) {
    let delta = math.abs(angle2 - angle1)
    if (delta < 180) {
      delta = 360 - delta
    }

    return delta
  }`

Comment: When you are working with angles you should never do abs(). This mirros the angle about the y axis in your case. Keep in mind a standard unit circle has the angle 0 start at the 3 o clock position. And in your question green point should always be A or B, you can't make it inconsistent like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply A - B and then add or subtract 360 as needed.

Formula that works for all cases:

> ((A mod 360) - (B mod 360) + 720) mod 360

Edited: Add 720 instead of 360, in case A is negative and B is positive and you end up with less than -360.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JerMah, but when implementing your formula in javascript I have :  


    function diff(angleA, angleB) {  
      return ((angleA % 360 - angleB % 360) + 360) % 360  
    }
  

    `diff(15, 45) = 330` => Correct  

    `diff(45, 135) = 270` => Instead of 90 wanted. (figure B)

Comment: I said A - B, you did B - A in the second case. A is always the green point. 15 - 45 +360 = 330 and 135 - 45 = 90.